# What module for detecting URLs?

Tags: perl, cpan

Is there a Perl module that detects URLs?

For example, if I have a string `'xyz'` it says that is not a URL, and if I have a string `'http://stackoverflow.com'`, it says that is a URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is detect if you've got a URI, you can use [Data:Validate:URI](http://search.cpan.org/~sonnen/Data-Validate-URI-0.06/lib/Data/Validate/URI.pm).  If you need to do parsing as well, you should use [URI:URL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI/URL.pm).

Good luck.

Comment: and if you are looking for a URL in a larger body of text, URI::Find

Comment: The beauty of CPAN: a hundred different ways to do something.

Comment: ? no, 3 ways to do 3 different things, in this case

Comment: I was speaking metaphorically.  Perl lives by a model of TIMTOWTDI - "There's more than one way to do it."

Comment: I've marked this as accepted since this seems the closest to what I was looking for. Thank you and other other answerers.

Answer (score 5):

For all your URL parsing and manipulation needs, you want [`URI::URL`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI/URL.pm).

Comment: Why [URI::URL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI/URL.pm) instead of [URI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI.pm)? URI::URL is just a backwards compatibility wrapper around URI.

Comment: @tobyink: Your one-upmanship doesn't help any one.

Comment: @Borodin That is a perfectly legitimate observation; wrappers exist to prevent the breakage of legacy code--relying on them for the production of new code is foolish at best.